# How to get the edges of a polygon as LineStrings?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have several square polygons in a list, how to get directly the list of all the LineStrings representing their four edges ? With a list comprehension using `polygon.exterior.coords` for example.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
frame = gpd.read_file("my_file.geojson")
liste = frame["geometry"].tolist()
```

Comment: The obvious answer would be to use `exterior` (or `boundary`) in a list comprehension, but you already wrote that in the question, which makes me wonder what you are actually asking about.

Comment: How to generate the LineStrings of the 4 edges with the coordinates of each polygon given by `exterior` ? `boundary` gives me a unique LineString for each polygon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString

poly = Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0]])
b = poly.boundary.coords
linestrings = [LineString(b[k:k+2]) for k in range(len(b) - 1)]
print([list(ls.coords) for ls in linestrings])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
frame[0]['geometry']['type']  # expect 'Polygon', or other geometry type
```

If it is 'Polygon', you can get a long list of the geometry coordinates from this command:-

```
coord_list = frame[0]['geometry']['coordinates']
```

But you may get errors. In such cases, you need to post all relevant code and error messages.

If the `coord_list` is good for creation of `LineString`, then, you can proceed as next steps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but `polygon.exterior.coords` gives me this directly. I want to create LineString of the edges of polygons.

Comment: @Tim Please post some of them for sample. Not need the real data. Simplified data is OK.